Memory leak on multiple connections in net/http Golang
I have the following function:
var client = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
}

func scan(ip string) (error, string, string, string) {
    resp, err := client.Get("http://" + ip)

    // Closing unused connections
    client.CloseIdleConnections()

    if err != nil {
        return err, "", "", ""
    }

    headers := buildHeaders(resp.Header)
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    // Closing the response body
    resp.Body.Close()

    return err, headers, string(body), resp.Status
}

This code leads to a huge memory leak. In the process of debugging it turned out that the following happens in net/http in the queueForIdleConn() function in the transport.go file:
if t.idleConnWait == nil {
    t.idleConnWait = make(map[connectMethodKey]wantConnQueue)
}
q := t.idleConnWait[w.key]
q.cleanFront()
q.pushBack(w)
t.idleConnWait[w.key] = q
return false

It turns out that in idleConnWait = {map[http.connectMethodKey]http.wantConnQueue} new elements are constantly written, but judging by the size is never released. What is the correct way to clear this array?
Comments:
The program throws connections to a set of addresses 95% of which are invalid (not responding).
This function is run in a large number of goroutines at once (go scan()).

Waiting: normal program operation
In reality: memory leak

The code you've shown can't result in a memory leak, but you could be using excessive amount of memory for all the connections. Rather than storing the connections then trying to close idle ones with CloseIdleConnections, don't allow them in the first place. Try settingClose: true on the Request, and/or DisableKeepAlives on the transport. You can also set lower level DialContext and ResponseHeaderTimeout timeouts on the transport to catch timeouts in a more granular fashion.
